# How to extend PATH of LaunchAgents in ~/Library/LaunchAgents?

Tags: launchd, zsh

I noticed that `~/.zshrc` is not loaded... I need to add `/usr/local/bin` to PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to extend PATH of LaunchAgents in ~/Library/LaunchAgents?

You can use the following for example:

```xml
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin</string>
</dict>
```

Add it to your **XML Plist** *file* in an appropriate manner so it doesn't break the other *key* groups.

I'd place it at the top of the **XML Plist** *file*, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin</string>
    </dict>
```

Then the rest of your **XML Plist** *file*.

---

**Notes:**

- If my **XML Plist** *file* in **~/Library/LaunchAgents** is calling a *shell script*, I typically set the `PATH` (`path`) in my *scripts* as well as at times use the *fully qualified pathname* of the *executable*.
- When using **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend reading the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`.

  - You can read the *manual page* for `command`  in **Terminal** by typing `command` and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to know how to fix `scandir: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`? I believe it has something to do with "Security & Privacy". Why doesn't the LaunchAgent work but running the command it runs in a terminal works fine?

Comment: Actually, a better question would be what runs `ProgramArguments`?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405872/how-to-fix-launchagent-scandir-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-error