# How to fix LaunchAgent scandir: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted error?

Tags: launchd

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/usr/local/bin/backup.sh</string>
</array>
```

Running `/usr/local/bin/backup.sh` requires access to `~/Documents`.

My gut feeling is I have to allow an app in "Security & Privacy", but which one and is that secure?

Comment: Sometimes I feel the level of security **Apple** imposes in **macOS** is a bit ridiculous! Anyway, `launchd` is responsible for running of **agents** and **daemons** in the various locations they are stored. The user cannot selectively manually add _programs_ to **Files and Folders** under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**, the system has to prompt the user for permission. However, the user can add `launchd` to **Full Disk Access**. Don't know if this will solve your issue but it's a place to start. It might also be worth seeing the _code_ in the _shell script_.

Comment: When using **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend reading the _manual pages_ for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`. You can read the _manual page_ for `command ` in **Terminal** by typing `command` and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: Thanks for your help @user3439894. I found how to solve the problem. See answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked!

I created an app using "Script Editor" that runs `/usr/local/bin/borg-backup.sh` using `zsh`.

```
do shell script "zsh /usr/local/bin/borg-backup.sh"
```

I then exported the app to `/Applications/borg-backup.app` clicking "File" then "Export..." choosing "Application" for "File Format".

Finally, I updated `~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.borg-backup.plist`.

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>open</string>
  <string>/Applications/borg-backup.app</string>
</array>
```

The first time the launch agent ran, a prompt asked me to grant `borg-backup.app` access to `~/Documents`.